# Copy files from subfolders to the nearest parent directory in Unix

Tags: unix

I have the following folder structure:

> ```
> Folder1       
> --FolderA    
>   --Gex_experiments     
> --FolderB     
>  --Gex_experiments     
> --FolderC    
>  --Gex_experiments    
> .......      
> --FolderAYCD
>  --Gex_experiments
> ```

In each Gex_experiments folder there's a *_GEX.txt file I would like to move to FolderA in the case of Gex_experiments folder under FolderA, to FolderB in the case of Gex_experiments folder under FolderB and so on.

Can anyone help me please?

Best!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From folder1 you can run:

```
for file in *; do
  if [ -d $file ]; then
    cd $file; mv Gex_experiments/*_GEX.txt ./; cd ..;
  fi
done
```

Comment: Unfortunately it does not work...The file is not moved in the parent dir :-(

Comment: I edited my post, it should work now, I forgot '$' prefix for $file variable